# Subtract Int with firestore value in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, google-cloud-firestore, uitextfield

I'm trying to make a coupon system in my app.
When a user has typed in a textfield it should look for a coupon that matches the text.
I've managed to retrieve the correct document but i don't know how to subtract the document fieldvalue "percentOff" from my cart's subtotal.
Here is some code:

My code for getting the document:

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        if textField == couponTxt {
            let collectionRef = db.collection("coupons")
            collectionRef.whereField("name", isEqualTo: couponTxt.text!).getDocuments { (snapshot, err) in
                if let err = err {
                    print("Error getting document: \(err)")
                } else {
                    for document in (snapshot?.documents)! {
                        if document == document {
                            let data = document.data()
                            let couponData = Coupon.init(data: data)
                          print(document.documentID)
                            }
                            
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

This is my model for getting the data for the coupons:

```
 init(data: [String: Any]) {

        self.name = data["name"] as? String ?? ""
        self.id = data["id"] as? String ?? ""
        self.percentOff = data["percentOff"] as? Double ?? 0.0
        self.kronerOff = data["kronerOff"] as? Double ?? 0.0
        self.usageLeft = data["usageLeft"] as? Int ?? 0

    }
```

Code from my PaymentCart class - the subtotal:

```
 var subtotal: Int {
        var amount = 0
        for item in cartItem {
            let priceOere = Int(item.price * 100)
            amount += priceOere
        }
        return amount
    }
```

So my question is - now that I can get the correct document how can I get the value from percentOff and minus my current subtotal with that.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you get the coupon document and create the `Coupon` object, you must put it somewhere if you want to later access it. Right now, you don't do anything with `couponData` except initialize it. `subtotal` is a computed property that needs to access `couponData` so `couponData` must be within the scope of this computed property, so just make that happen.  For example, if `subtotal` is in a view controller, then just make `couponData` an instance property in that same view controller. And then `subtotal` may look something like this:

```
var coupon: Coupon?

var subtotal: Int {
    var amount = 0
    for item in cartItem {
        let priceOere = Int(item.price * 100)
        amount += priceOere
    }

    if let coupon = coupon {
        let discountRate = 1 - coupon.percentOff // assuming a 10% off coupon is 0.1 and not 10.0
        return amount * discountRate
    } else {
        return amount
    }
}
```

But before you get here, you must assign a value to `coupon`:

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    if textField == couponTxt {
        let collectionRef = db.collection("coupons")
        collectionRef.whereField("name", isEqualTo: couponTxt.text!).getDocuments { (snapshot, err) in
            if let err = err {
                print("Error getting document: \(err)")
            } else {
                for document in (snapshot?.documents)! {
                    if document == document {
                        let data = document.data()
                        let couponData = Coupon(data: data)
                        self.coupon = couponData // assign it to the instance property
                        print(document.documentID)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! My subtotal is not in the same viewcontroller as the textfield. It is in a final class called _PaymenCart. How should i do it then?

Comment: That's entirely up to you. This decision is part of a larger decision you must make about the overall organization of data. It wouldn't be the worst idea in the world to keep shopping cart data in the same object as coupon data, right? And perhaps all that this data-manager object does is store shopping data. And perhaps it's a singleton or it isn't–all decisions you must make. But just to get the ball rolling, just for now, make it a global variable and confirm that it all works and then decide where to put it and how to structure your data.

Comment: Alright. It didn't work. I made the subtotal a public var.. But the subtotal outcome after typing a coupon was totally off..

Comment: There's a difference between a `public` variable and a global variable. `public` is a control access level in Swift and global is simply placing the variable outside of any objects so that every object can access it. Make `coupon` a global variable (again, just for testing) and confirm that the discount is accurately applied.

Comment: I've done that now. It doesn't work either. Nothing happens :/

Comment: Now you have some debugging to do and find out what exactly is broken. Put print statements everywhere and see what’s not executing. Print in the Firestone return and make sure you’re getting back a document and then print the coupon value and make sure it’s correct before creating the coupon object. Do this everywhere until you find out what isn’t working.

Comment: Okay. Thank you for your time! :)

Comment: Just take everything step by step and you’ll find it. First make sure the document itself exists in the database. Then make sure you can accurately get the document and you can accurately get their values. And definitely make sure that the data types match—if it’s an integer in the database make sure you’re unwrapping it as an integer here. Then make sure the custom object is being properly initialized. Feel free to keep us updated here in the comment section.

Comment: When I'm printing the values of the coupon it all matches the database.. But the solution above doesn't seem to work. Would it be totally off to use a get/set ? And then say something like PaymentCart.subtotal -= couponData.percentOff?

Comment: When you print the `discountRate` inside the `subtotal` variable, what do you get? It should be exactly the value you printed in the Firestore return. If it isn't then you're losing the data in the initialization of the custom `Coupon` object.

Comment: Hey sorry for the late answer! I have been working with it for the last week and finally found the solution. Your code worked, I just had to change the subtotal variable to Double (and made sure all other variables were double instead of int). Then I used your code in the class PaymentCart under subtotal. Then it all worked! Thanks a lot :)